# Unhandles Runtime Error.....: Hydration failed etc

Tags: next.js, runtime-error, next.js13

I am making a website using Next.js and the above error is shown every time.

Don't know what is wrong in my code.

Errors shown:
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.  Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .  See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Error: There was an error while hydrating.

`
"use client";

import { Menu } from "lucide-react";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
Sheet,
SheetContent,
SheetTrigger
} from "@/components/ui/sheet"
import Sidebar from "@/components/sidebar";

const MobileSidebar =() => {
return (










);
}

export default MobileSidebar;
`

Code should actually work and no errors should be shown.
thanks a lot to those who will help !

Answer (score 0):

"use client";

import { Menu } from "lucide-react";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
Sheet,
SheetContent,
SheetTrigger
} from "@/components/ui/sheet"
import Sidebar from "@/components/sidebar";

const MobileSidebar =() => {
return (










);
}

export default MobileSidebar;

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**